Cannot upgrade 23.10 Server to 24.04
I was wanting to upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 without waiting for August for the 24.04.1 release. I first upgraded the server to 23.10 (latest-stable) but then kept receiving an error when upgrading from 23.10 to 24.04.
The command entered was sudo do-release-upgrade, not with the -d flag.
The error kept saying that the command terminated with a status code of 1, and it was trying to calculate the package changes or something before it did that.
